# What is the format of the timestamp in InstallShield's ISString table?

Tags: string, localization, timestamp, installshield

I was recently trying to determine the answer to this question. The only post I was able to find on the topic was this old unanswered [post](https://community.flexerasoftware.com/showthread.php?117149-How-are-TimeStamp-values-generated-in-ISString) on Flexera's website.

I wanted to know the answer to this question to incorporate in a tool for managing string translations. I already discovered the answer (my coworker and I spent the better half of our day trying to figure it out) but I thought I'd post the question/answer on Stack Overflow just in case someone else searches for it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is that the timestamp is a 32-bit integer with different bits representing different parts of the date.

Here's how it breaks down

```
Bits 1-5  : The Day of the Month [1-31] (end range could be 28-31 depending on month)
Bits 6-9  : The Month [1-12]
Bits 10-16: The Year after 1980 (only goes to year 2107) [0-127]
Bits 17-21: (?) Seconds rounded to even (only 5 bits so can only contain 31 values) [0-30]
Bits 22-27: Minutes [0-59]
Bits 28-32: Hours from 12 AM [0-23]
```

If the 32-bit integer is an invalid date it's evaluated to a default date `Dec/30/1899 12:00 AM`

Here is an example:

```
  -------BINARY-32-bit-Integer-----          |   Decimal  |   Date String  
DOM   Month   Year  Seconds*2   Min   Hour   |            |               
00111 0111  0010000   00001    010000 00000  |  999295488 | Jul/07/1996 12:16 AM
 7      7     16      1         16     0
```

Here is some C# code written to convert between DateTime and the string representation of the ISString timestamp (Small Disclaimer: this code doesn't currently handle invalid timestamp input):

```
    private static int bitsPerDOM = 5;
    private static int bitsPerMonth = 4;
    private static int bitsPerYear = 7;
    private static int bitsPerEvenSecond = 5;
    private static int bitsPerMinute = 6;
    private static int bitsPerHour = 5;

    private static int startYear = 1980;

    public static string getISTimestamp(DateTime date)
    {
        int[] shiftValues = { bitsPerDOM, bitsPerMonth, bitsPerYear, bitsPerEvenSecond, bitsPerMinute, bitsPerHour };
        int[] dateValues = { date.Day, date.Month, date.Year -startYear, date.Second/2, date.Minute, date.Hour };
        int shift = 32;
        int dateInt = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < dateValues.Length; i++)
        {
            shift -= shiftValues[i];
            dateInt |= (dateValues[i] << shift);
        }

        return dateInt.ToString();
    }

    public static DateTime getTimeFromISTimestampStr(string ISTimestampStr)
    {
        int timestampInt = Int32.Parse(ISTimestampStr);
        int dom = getBits(timestampInt, 0, 4);
        int month = getBits(timestampInt, 5, 8);
        int year = startYear + getBits(timestampInt, 9, 15);
        int seconds = getBits(timestampInt, 16, 20) * 2;
        int minutes = getBits(timestampInt, 21, 26);
        int hours = getBits(timestampInt, 27, 31);            
        return new DateTime(year, month, dom, hours, minutes, seconds);
    }

    private static int getBits(int n, int start, int end)
    {
        //Clear left bits by shifting
        n <<= start;            
        n >>= 31 + start - end; //Shift to the right
        return n;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the research, it helped me to decode the InstallShield timestamp for a project I was investigating - here is my extract in perl for the sample decimal date above:
`($dom,$mon,$y1980,$s2,$min,$h)= map { oct "0b$_" } unpack "a5a4a7a5a6a5", scalar reverse unpack "b*", pack "l", 999295488`
prints as `00/07/1996 00:16:02` given `printf "%02d/%02d/%04d %02d:%02d:%02d\n", $mom, $dom, 1980+$y1980,$h, $min, 2*$s2`